# Is there a difference to how the open api spec is generated between swashbuckle CLI and when running app?

Tags: swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a case where I want to get the swagger spec using the cli, but it fails with this error:

```
Unhandled exception. Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Failed to generate Operation for action - Elkjop.Bonus.BonusManager.Controllers.ArticleMasterdataController.GetCategories (Elkjop.Bonus.BonusManager). See inner exception
 ---> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Failed to generate schema for type - System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Elkjop.Bonus.BonusManager.Dto.ArticleGroupingDto]. See inner exception
 ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.DataContract Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.DataContract.ForDynamic(System.Type)'.
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft.NewtonsoftDataContractResolver.GetDataContractForType(Type type)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GetDataContractFor(Type modelType)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchemaForType(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(Type modelType, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, MemberInfo memberInfo, ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateSchema(Type type, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateSchema(Type type, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.CreateResponseMediaType(ModelMetadata modelMetadata, SchemaRepository schemaRespository)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<GenerateResponse>b__2(String contentType)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateResponse(ApiDescription apiDescription, SchemaRepository schemaRepository, String statusCode, ApiResponseType apiResponseType)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateResponses(ApiDescription apiDescription, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperation(ApiDescription apiDescription, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperation(ApiDescription apiDescription, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperations(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GeneratePaths(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String documentName, String host, String basePath)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_3(IDictionary`2 namedArgs) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 72
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 68
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 59
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 111
Finished (TagStatus.Failed) 'CreateOpenapiSpec' in 00:00:01.7477228
```

It works perfectly fine to go to the swagger url when running the app. I took for granted that the code to generate the actual json is the same, so I don't understand why the CLI would fail.

Command I use to run the cli

```
dotnet swagger tofile --output .output/spec.json --host "<hostname>" path.to.dll v1
```

The packages I have in the project:

```
    <PackageReference Include="ITDS.Util.Logging.Splunk" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Snowflake.Data" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="5.6.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft" Version="5.6.3" />
```

The action method looks like this:

```
        [HttpGet("categories")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<ArticleGroupingDto>> GetCategories()
        {
            var result = await _repo.GetCategories();
            return result.Select(x => _groupingMapper.Map(x));
        }
```

And the dto like this:

```
    public class ArticleGroupingDto
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

So nothing to complicated.

**Update:**

Seems to be related to newtonsoft somehow, if I remove

```
services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
```

the generation works... but then I don't have the functionality I want.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/issues/285#issuecomment-881294702

Answer (score 2):

The problem was related to versions. Updating `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft` fixed it.